# No colord package error while compiling GNOME3

Tags: 11.04, gnome, compiling

I am getting the following error while compiling gnome 3 from source. Any idea how to get past the error?

```
configure: error: Package requirements (colord >= 0.1.8) were not met:

No package 'colord' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables COLORD_CFLAGS
and COLORD_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the colord package. Unfortunately you need to build that one too.

When you let jhbuild run and it complains, open a new terminal and run:

```
    cd ~/gnome-shell/source/ # or wherever your GS sources are
    git clone git://gitorious.org/colord/master.git colord
    cd colord
    ./autogen.sh --prefix="$HOME"/gnome-shell/install/ # change if you install it elsewhere
    make && make install
```

This will download, build and (locally) install colord. Then go back to the other terminal and choose the point that runs the configuration phase again (AFAIK the first option).

Comment: The Darktable PPA,for lcms2 dependency:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pmjdebruijn/darktable-release`
`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install lcms2*`

Answer (score 1):

Use `sudo apt install libcolord-dev`. I got the package name through `apt-file search colord | grep "dev"`. The reason for using dev specifically is mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/921888/when-should-i-install-dev-package)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I can't give you an answer to fix the problem. But, I also tried installing Gnome 3, and it didn't work on my system. Gnome 3 is very buggy right now, so I would wait a few weeks until it becomes more stable. I'm perfectly fine with using Ubuntu Classic, until either Unity or Gnome 3 become less buggy. :)